# wordpress custom post type archive returns no posts

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, archive

I am trying to get posts related to custom taxonomy. 
I have a new CPT called `article`.
I have two custom taxonomies related to the `CPT`:`tags` and `cats`
I can see the cpt items in a custom archive page called `archive-article.php`.

the problem is this, I created two new files: `taxonomy-cats.php` and 'taxonomy-tags.php' the content of this files are exacley as the `archive-article.php`. file.

I get a massage that nothing was found. I checked and I know that there are custom posts related to this taxonomy value.

This is the url I receive the empty archive:
'http://localhost/broker/cats/sales/'

What can be the problem?

Thank you!

This is the taxonomy code:

```
 function create_cats_taxonomy() {

   $labels = array(
     'name' => _x( 'cats', 'taxonomy general name' ),
     'singular_name' => _x( 'cat', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
     'search_items' =>  __( 'search items' ),
     'all_items' => __( 'all items' ),
     'parent_item' => __( 'parent item' ),
     'parent_item_colon' => __( 'parent item colon:' ),
     'edit_item' => __( 'edit item' ), 
     'update_item' => __( 'update item' ),
     'add_new_item' => __( 'add new item' ),
     'new_item_name' => __( 'new cat' ),
     'menu_name' => __( 'cat'),
   );    

 // Now register the taxonomy

   register_taxonomy('cats',array('article'), array(
     'hierarchical' => true,
     'labels' => $labels,
     'show_ui' => true,
     'show_admin_column' => true,
     'query_var' => true,
     'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'cats' ),
   ));

 }

 add_action( 'init', 'create_cats_taxonomy' );
```